# In Cloud Functions, where to import the Firestore `Query` type from?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am trying to `import` the [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query) **type** in one of my TypeScript file without success. Can't find it in `firebase-admin` package, and when I try to use `@firebase/firestore-types` (which is advised to not use as types are supposed along with firebase) it is complaining `Cannot find module '@firebase/firestore-types' from...`.

Where should I import it from? `firebase` package has it but is for client SDK.

Comment: ...same for `GeoPoint` type, but I guess the answer for the above will also give the answer for `GeoPoint`.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the types via the declared namespace in `firestore.d.ts`. It is named `FirebaseFirestore`.

In your case use:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
...

const query: FirebaseFirestore.Query = ...
```